# How can I get cabal to install acid-state?

Tags: haskell, cabal, acid-state

I'm a newbie to Haskell, and wanted to try the acid-state library, but I get the following output when trying to install it:

```
>cabal install acid-state
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring acid-state-0.7.5...
Building acid-state-0.7.5...
Preprocessing library acid-state-0.7.5...
[ 1 of 15] Compiling Data.Acid.CRC    ( src\Data\Acid\CRC.hs, dist\build\Data\Ac
id\CRC.o )
[ 2 of 15] Compiling Paths_acid_state ( dist\build\autogen\Paths_acid_state.hs,
dist\build\Paths_acid_state.o )
[ 3 of 15] Compiling Data.Acid.Archive ( src\Data\Acid\Archive.hs, dist\build\Da
ta\Acid\Archive.o )
[ 4 of 15] Compiling FileIO           ( src-win32\FileIO.hs, dist\build\FileIO.o
 )

src-win32\FileIO.hs:43:5:
    Not in scope: `catchIO'
    Perhaps you meant `catch' (imported from Prelude)

src-win32\FileIO.hs:55:6:
    Not in scope: `tryE'
    Perhaps you meant `try' (imported from Control.Exception.Extensible)

src-win32\FileIO.hs:56:6:
    Not in scope: `tryE'
    Perhaps you meant `try' (imported from Control.Exception.Extensible)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
acid-state-0.7.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bug in the library. Looks like they forgot an import, but I can't figure out where they intended to get `catchIO` and `tryE` from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. Temporary workaround: install an older version of acid-state

```
cabal install acid-state-0.7.0
```

Comment: That worked for me! I'd give you points, but I don't have enough reputation yet.